# Where can I download the pager-container CSS for bootstrap?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have been given this for a MVC razor pager and it wants a `pager-container` class. But I can't find it anywhere. My pager displays in a bad way due to this. Where can I find this css class?

Im using `PagedList.Core.MVC` package in netcoreapp 1.1

```
<pager class="pager-container" list="@Model" options="@PagedListRenderOptions.TwitterBootstrapPager" asp-action="NieuwsOverzicht" asp-controller="Nieuws" />
```

This is how it displays:

```
- Previous
- 1
- 2
- Next
```

Comment: Bootstrap 4 removed the `.pager` element but it is still part of Bootstrap 3: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#pagination-pager  Make sure you're using the correct CSS and syntax.

Comment: Wrong CSS file! I fixed it thank you

Comment: Could you tell me how I can customize the pager